# How to process messages from many users simultaneously[python-telegram-bot Webhooks]?

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, python-multiprocessing, python-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I have 2 py. files:

**1.** I have 4 workers. Each worker works 10 seconds. The total execution time of the program is 10 seconds. So all workers works simultaneously.

```
import asyncio
from time import sleep, time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

num_jobs = 4
queue = asyncio.Queue()
executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_jobs)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

def work():
    sleep(10)

async def producer():
    tasks = [loop.run_in_executor(executor, work) for _ in range(num_jobs)]
    for f in asyncio.as_completed(tasks, loop=loop):
        results = await f
        await queue.put(results)

async def consumer():
    completed = 0
    while completed < num_jobs:
        job = await queue.get()
        completed += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = time()
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(producer(), consumer()))
    print("duration", time() - s)
```

**2.** Python Telegram Bot, that uses Webhooks for receiving messages from users. This bot receives messages from user and **after 10 seconds** send echo-message to user. But this not gives me that result that I give in the first case. In this second case, messages are not processed simultaneously.

```
import asyncio
import logging
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils.executor import start_webhook
from aiogram import Bot, types
from bot_files.config import *


bot = Bot(token=bot_token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# webhook settings
WEBHOOK_HOST = f'https://2568-176-8-60-184.ngrok.io'
WEBHOOK_PATH = f'/webhook/{bot_token}'
WEBHOOK_URL = f'{WEBHOOK_HOST}{WEBHOOK_PATH}'

# webserver settings
WEBAPP_HOST = '0.0.0.0'
WEBAPP_PORT = os.getenv('PORT', default=5000)


async def on_startup(dispatcher):
    await bot.set_webhook(WEBHOOK_URL, drop_pending_updates=True)


async def on_shutdown(dispatcher):
    await bot.delete_webhook()

@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    await message.answer(message.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    start_webhook(
        dispatcher=dp,
        webhook_path=WEBHOOK_PATH,
        skip_updates=True,
        on_startup=on_startup,
        on_shutdown=on_shutdown,
        host=WEBAPP_HOST,
        port=WEBAPP_PORT,
    )
```

I want to put `@dp.message_handler()` in `loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(producer()))` such a `producer()`. But I can't put decorator as a parameter. My total question is: How to process messages from many users simultaneously for telegram bot on Python, such in the first case? I know how to make it for long polling. Is it possible make it for Webhooks???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your bot works on Webhooks, Aiogram has special decorator for simultaneous messages processing from many users - `async_task`: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/_modules/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.html#Dispatcher.async_task.